# Reading and parsing large files

Tags: node.js, stream, fs

I have very large file which I need to parse and read the data between the "BEGIN DATA" and "END DATA" delimiters, then do something like decoding the block.

I can open the file easily using the "fs" library like so:

```
  fs.readFile(files[0], 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(data)
 });
```

However, I need to then read the data between the delimiters in blocks via a stream so not use large amounts of memory.

```
        -----BEGIN DATA-----
        MIIEzDCCArSgAwIBAgIVCugKYzMN5ra8zPWxYE8pUU9SxjYSMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB
        CwUAMHAxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkdCMRUwEwYDVQQIDAxXYXJ3aWNrc2hpcmUxEDAOBgNV
        BAcMB1dhcndpY2sxEDAOBgNVBAoMB0VudHJ1c3QxETAPBgNVBAsMCFBLSSBURUFN
        -----END DATA-----
        -----BEGIN DATA-----
        MIIETzCCAjegAwIBAgIVBShP2Mx74DZEyNKwYZZPGntRmSWnMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB
        DQUAMHIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkdCMRUwEwYDVQQIDAxXYXJ3aWNrc2hpcmUxEDAOBgNV
        BAcMB1dhcndpY2sxDDAKBgNVBAoMA0lCTTERMA8GA1UECwwIUEtJIFRFQU0xGTAX
        5/62
        -----END DATA-----
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use a stream library coupled to node's `fs.createReadStream`, in your case the `splitBy` method in [Highland.js](http://highlandjs.org/#splitBy) would be suitable:

```
_(fs.createReadStream(files[0], { encoding: 'utf8' }))
  .splitBy('-----BEGIN DATA-----')
  .splitBy('-----END DATA-----')
  .each(_.log)
```

Comment: Thanks this looks interesting. However, I can't quit work out how to use the library. I did this `const readFile = _.wrapCallback(fs.readFile);
    const stream = _(['myfile.txt']).map(readFile).parallel(2);` but can't work out how to get the data

Comment: Try the example code provided. The callback provided to `_.each() ` will be called with the content of each of your delimited blocks which you can then `split` to process line-by-line.